# Rest Client Timeout - Implementation specific?

Tags: rest, wildfly

I am using Wildfly and I started to write some clients to connect to other backends. Now I want to set some timeouts to my stubs to avoid that my application performance suffers from slow or not responding backends.

The connection works very well, but when I wanted to set the timeout I realized that I have to fall back to the client implementation so I used resteasy (used in Wildfly afaik).

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.8.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Is there really no standard way to accomplish that? 
The resteasy documentation is quite short. Does anyone have a good source with examples for setting a timeout there?

greetings
m

PS:

```
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    Builder request = client.target(ADRESS_BALANCE).request();
    return request.get(BigInteger.class);
```

Comment: Show us the code that uses a client.

Comment: Atm it is quite simple. I removed the LoggingHandler, Errorhandling and the Adress for better overview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RestEasy way to set socketTimeout:

```
    ResteasyClientBuilder builder = (ResteasyClientBuilder) ClientBuilder.newBuilder();
    builder.socketTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

If you would like to use standard way check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22672664/setting-request-timeout-for-jax-rs-2-0-client-api)

Comment: Already checked this answer. One is Jersey specific and the Future Method does not work with a Socket timeout. In worst case the Socket hangs and so does the thread of the future. Will go with your answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Instead socketTimeout to me it works conectTimeout and readTimeout,  this solution is implementation specific but it's ok, Thanks!.
        
`builder.connectTimeout(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
builder.readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`