# How to add timeout for my jax-rs rest webservices

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I've already created my rest webservices (around 250 services in 70 java files). I want to add response timeout handler for all of the api's. Instead of adding it to individually 250 places, is there a way I can handle this with out touching existing services ?

Comment: Perhaps on the client side, like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22672664/setting-request-timeout-for-jax-rs-2-0-client-api.

Comment: In the link below we are taking taking about the clients , but we need to do it for the webservice endpoints and the timeout for there response